# mercedes benz 308D precombustion chamber is leaking compression after tightenning. is there any thing I can use to colse the remaing air pockets

Tags: mercedes-benz

after tightening in the lock cap of the precombustion chamber compression still find its way out, we cant remove the cap out as we are afraid it will come out together with the threads as it has happened before and we an engineer made a new locker(bigger size) and tapped new threads in the cylinder head. We have tried using trinerpon, epoxy and prime bond but to no luck, whats the best solution for this problem

Comment: Is this a 380d?